# Getting a 404 if %3F or is in querystring

Tags: c#, query-string

I´m having som problems with backlinks containing %3F and %3D.

It´s workng fine if it´s "?" and "=" that are used in the querystring, but as sone as the links contains the other versions I get a 404.

Any one that has an answer to this problem.??
Using Microsoft .NET Framework version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET version:2.0.50727.4955

Answer (score 1):

It's bug in 4.0. You need to use something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("AddressValidation", new { subtype = "AdditionalClientDetails_SubmitButton" });
```

Comment: Do you have a link about this bug?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [URL decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) these links.

This will decode `%3F` back to `?`:

```
Server.UrlDecode(myURL);
```

Comment: The problem with URL decode is that the page don´t even reach the page load. On localhost I get a 400 error og the website the 404 http://www.thecurrencyrates.eu/Default.aspx%3Fsid%3DPLN

Comment: @user689756 - Where are these links coming from?